# How set only the text at centre of div if inside there's another div?

Tags: jquery, html, css, flexbox

Hello i have two div `#box-first` and the children `#first`
I want to put a text inside `#box-first` in the middle (at the centre) but don't want to see white space o empty space cause the text.

In this example i put the text inside other div.... but if this div (`#n1`) has a small `width` the text is not full visible.

```
 <div id="page">
  <div id="box-first">
    <div id="first">
      <div id="n1">
        1500 text
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

So how i can solve this ?
I tried using `position: relative` but i can't able to put the text at centre.

I created jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rdxnvjpw/28/

The problem is at second "bar"

Thanks a lot and sorry for my english..

Comment: Looks like the issue is slightly different from described (sometimes these are hard to describe): your 2nd "bar" value is not showing, but it *is* centred - it's overlapping the sides.

Comment: Alternatively, if you want the value to be centred within the box (not just within the value part) then don't nest it inside 'first'.

Comment: Yes really difficult to describe, more for me because i'm italian... anyway i ask if is possible to put the text not like my example (because i know is correct and is at the centre but width is small) but outside

Comment: @freedomn-m if i move #n2 outside #second like two siblings than is a problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `position:absolute` and make it relative to the grand-parent element and not the parent element:

```js
//FIRST BAR
$('#first').addClass('first-start');

setTimeout(function() {
  $('#first').addClass('first-pause');
}, 1500);

//SECOND BAR
$('#second').addClass('second-start');

setTimeout(function() {
  $('#second').addClass('second-pause');
}, 200);
```

```css
#page {
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 8px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#box-first,
#box-second {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  position:relative;
}

@keyframes first {
  0% {
    background-color: green;
    width: 0%
  }
  33% {
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 33%
  }
  66% {
    background-color: orange;
    width: 66%
  }
  100% {
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%
  }
}

@keyframes second {
  0% {
    background-color: green;
    width: 0%
  }
  33% {
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 33%
  }
  66% {
    background-color: orange;
    width: 66%
  }
  100% {
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%
  }
}

#first, #second {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.first-start, .second-start  {
  animation: first 2s linear;
}

.first-pause, .second-pause {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}



#n1, #n2 {
  font-size: 19px;
  line-height:50px;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: bold;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  text-align:center;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="page">
  <div id="box-first">
    <div id="first">
      <div id="n1">
        1500
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="box-second">
    <div id="second">
      <div id="n2">
        1500
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```